# Show that Aut $(C_n)=D_n$

Tags: graph-theory, algebraic-graph-theory

Problem statement: I need to find out Aut $(C_n)$  is isomorphic to $D_n$.

I already know that it is isomorphic, so now all I need to do is to prove it.

Any help is appreciated. I was hoping for a duplicate post, but couldn't find it.
Thank you!

Comment: please can you give the definition of $Aut(C_n)$ you are using? It's sometimes leading to confusions.

Comment: An automorphism of a graph is an isomorphism of the graph to itself.

Comment: $C_n$ is also the cyclic group of order $n$. It has a different automorphism group.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly note that any automorphism can be obtained in this way: A given vertex $v$ may be mapped to any of the $n$ vertices available (including itself). As soon as that is done, an adjacent vertex to $v$ has only two choices left: it can either be in the counter clockwise direction to $v$ or in the clockwise direction to $v$. Once that choice is also made, no other choices are required. Hence we get $2n$ automorphisms this way and there can be no others.

Also, it is clear that two kinds of automorphisms suffice to generate this group: rotation, and swapping the notion of clockwise and counter clockwise (assuming we draw the cycle graph as equally spaced points on the unit circle; there is no loss of generality in doing that). But both these automorphisms also generate the dihedral group $D_n$ which also has $2n$ elements. It follows that $A(C_n)=D_n$.

This answer is taken from my blog post.